# SimpleAuth don't show login screen on instagram

Tags: ios, objective-c

I want implement logout logic in my instagram simple app. For this i use SimpleAuth library. First time, when user launch app everything is ok. There is code in viewDidLoad:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{

    .. some code for interface management

[SimpleAuth authorize:@"instagram" options:@{@"scope":@[@"likes"]} completion:^(NSDictionary* responseObject, NSError *error) {

   self.accessToken = responseObject[@"credentials"][@"token"];
   [userDefaults setObject:self.accessToken forKey:@"accessToken"];
   [userDefaults synchronize];

        NSLog(@"access token is afterProceed %@", self.accessToken);

    [self refresh];
    }];
}   else {
    [self refresh];
}
```

Fine, for logout logic i made simple method:

```
-(void)logoutButtonClicked{

    //Deleting token
    self.accessToken = nil;

    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];

    [userDefaults setObject:nil forKey:@"accessToken"];
    [userDefaults synchronize];

}
```

After that, `access.token` suppose to be nil, and it is `nil`.

However, when i re-launch app (with access token set to nil), it just load again, and when i look at `NSLog(@"access token is afterProceed %@", self.accessToken);` there is an access token (used didn't enter in second time).

Why is that happening? How to implement logout logic to an app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it's because of your SimpleAuth Authorization request is still validated for the Account that is currently signed in to Instagram. You must remove the access token (like you've already done) along with making a **Logout** call to inactivate the current Account that has already been Authorized.

One way that you could do this is by creating a `NSURLSessionTask` with a URL that uses: `https://www.instagram.com/accounts/logout/` to remove the current signed in user.